# meta char set UTF 8 encoding error

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta-tags

I have used the following code in my head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>
```

I have characters of other language which is supported by UTF-8 encoding in my web page. But when i save my html file it showed me error `The document's current encoding can not correctly save all of the characters within the document. You may want to change to UTF-8 or an encoding that supports the special characters in this document.`

I have already using UTF-8. How to fix this?

Comment: What Editor you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using UTF-8. You have just included some markup which tells the browser you are using UTF-8.

That error message sounds like it is coming from your editor. You need to configure your editor to save in UTF-8.

Comment: I haven't used any text editor. I just copy the tamil text from this site http://transport.tn.nic.in/transport/appointment.do?_tq=769a3656fe2a6a4bb5a52437936b9f21 and paste in my html file.

Comment: How do you paste it into an HTML file without using an editor?

Comment: *Macromedia* Dreamweaver? That's a very old bit of software (which explains why it isn't using UTF-8 by default). The answer is still the same: Configure it to save in UTF-8.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I presented the same issue after someone in my team had done the same mistake. I simply opened the file in Notepad++, clicked on the "encoding" tab, and then click to "Convert to UTF-8". The file was previously in ANSI.